# Prevent global, process, GLOBAL and root parameters from being iterated in a for loop

Tags: node.js, express

I have a function on one of my express application modules to which a parameter page is passed  :

```
module.exports.savePage =   function (page){


    console.log('-- Running M2PagePers.savePage.. ');

// il faut prévoir que quelqu'un utilise M2Page.save() pour un update
        for(var prop in page) {
            if(typeof(page[prop]) != 'function' && page.hasOwnProperty(prop))
            console.log('page['+ prop +'] : ' + page[prop] + ' propertyIsEnumerable ? ' + page.propertyIsEnumerable(prop));
        };
};
```

but i got some more properties in the page parameter which i didn't expect to see which are **global**, **process**, **GLOBAL** and **root**:

```
page[global] : [object global] propertyIsEnumerable ? true
page[process] : [object process] propertyIsEnumerable ? true
page[GLOBAL] : [object global] propertyIsEnumerable ? true
page[root] : [object global] propertyIsEnumerable ? true
page[console] : [object Object] propertyIsEnumerable ? true
page[url] : urltest1 propertyIsEnumerable ? true
page[type] : typetest1 propertyIsEnumerable ? true
page[definition] : deftest1 propertyIsEnumerable ? true
page[nb_visiteurs] : 656555 propertyIsEnumerable ? true
```

I don't really care from where they come (i guess they are some node.js global variables..) but even when i tried to make tests with hasOwnProperty and propertyIsEnumerable to filter the parameters iterated on the for loop , they are still there

**--- EDIT ----**
this is the **index.js** in which i defined a class **M2Page**, passing the page parameter occurs inside the **savePage** function by passing **this** to **M2PagePers.savePage(this);**

```
function M2Page (page, perspage) {


    this.url= null;
    this.type= null;
    this.definition= null; // [sect1, sect2, ... ,sectN]
    this.nb_visiteurs= null;
    this.droits_acces= null;
    this.secu_params= null;
    this.content= null;
    this.apparence=null;

    // permet d'initialiser la page avec page_props dans le constructeur
    flow.exec(
        function(){
            console.log('running flow m fn 1..');
            if(page != null && page != undefined)               
                (function (for_in_loop_cb) {
                        for(var prop in page) {
                            console.log('inside for in : setting this page\'s  ' + prop + ' to ' + page[prop]);
                            this[prop] = page[prop];
                        };
                    for_in_loop_cb();
                })(this);   

        },function(){
            console.log('running flow m fn 2.. ');
            if(perspage) savePage();
        }
    );

    //fonctions de persistance
    function savePage () {
        M2PagePers.savePage(this);
    };
```

Comment: the problem is that those properties are part of your page object not sure how they got there because i haven't seen your code, but if hasOwnProperty is not filtering them out, then they are not inherited but part of the object it self. If you know what properties you are expecting just create an array an iterate over it if you only know the ones you don't want then create an array and use it as exclusion. but with out seeing where is the page object coming or how is it build there is not much we can do

Comment: this was passed as the page parameters from another module which is a class containing properties. i will update the question to show the code doing it .

Comment: do you have control over that other module or is it a 3rd party module?

Comment: i do have control, these files are all inside the M2-Pages folder.

Comment: ok couple of things "use strict";  and when you use M2Page class use it with  new operator or Object.create otherwise is just a function and this. will refer to the global object since you are not using strict mode

Comment: When i added "use strict" to the index file, "this" became undefined. and i already have used new operator when i instancied the M2Page in the app.js main app file

Comment: your problem is that you are using this inside of save page, but savepage  is not a class member you either need to bind it to "this" or use a closure variable to access "this" try inseatd of calling. because of the level of nesting the closure variable is the simples way so as the first line of the class do var _this = this; and then use _this instead of this inside of the savepage function